# Pass adress of an object method to another object for it to call

Tags: c++, class, pointers, methods

Hi I am in C++ and I would like to pass the method of one object to another object of the same class:

```
class Object{
public:
    int id;
    int newId;
    Object(int _id){
       id = _id;
    };
    int (*function)();
    int someFunction(){
       return id*2;
    };
    void updateFunction(){
       newId = function();
    }
};

int someOtherFuntion(){
   return 3;
}

int main(){

    Object* obj[2];
    obj[0] = new Object(1);
    obj[1] = new Object(2);
    //next line is where the error happens
    obj[0]->function = &obj[1]->someFunction;
    obj[1]->function = &someOtherFuntion;

    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++){
       obj[i]->updateFunction();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Later on, I want to cycle through all objects with a loop, and call the corresponding function, sometimes a object method, and sometimes a regular function.

This returns error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say ‘&Object::someFunction’ [-fpermissive]

Comment: would this? What happened when you tried?

Comment: Please show real code. You are missing a `;` and `main` must return `int`. Also in your example it is irrelevant on what object the method is called. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do with you want with function pointers, because methods cannot be assigned to function pointers. But you can do what you want with `std::function` which is much more flexible than a function pointer and with a *lambda function* to bind your method to a particular object,

```
#include <functional>

class Object{
public:
    int id;
    int newId;
    Object(int _id){
       id = _id;
    };
    std::function<int()> function; // function is an int function with no parameters
    int someFunction(){
       return id*2;
    };
    void updateFunction(){
       newId = function();
    }
};

int someOtherFuntion(){
   return 3;
}

int main(){

    Object* obj[2];
    obj[0] = new Object(1);
    obj[1] = new Object(2);
    obj[0]->function = [=](){ return obj[1]->function(); }; // make a lambda function to bind function to obj[1]
    obj[1]->function = someOtherFuntion;

    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++){
       obj[i]->updateFunction();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: perfect! Is there by any chance a way to do this directly in the constructor?

Comment: The constructor for `Object`? Just pass in the function as you would any parameter to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> would this call obj2 and its method?

No. The program is ill-formed.

> or a copy of the method of obj2?

Functions cannot be copied.

> please note I don't want to use typedef because I am on a microcontroller

I see no relation between those two things at all.

> I would like to pass the method of one object to another object of the same class

Member functions are something that are the same for all instances of the same class. Their address does not differ from one object to another.

Judging by the example, it looks like you want to bind the object argument of a member function. You can use a function object to do that.

Comment: but they return the value from this object. In this case I would like obj.function to return the id of obj2

Comment: @michox Simply pass obj2 as the object argument to the member function.

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately I probably did not describe the purpose of the function properly I apologize. Let me reformulate my question and update my code